# Why doesn't the stroke of <marker/> work ? - SVG

Tags: css, svg

I tried adding a stroke to the  like this:
`<marker stroke="red" strokeWidth="2px"> <path d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" /> </marker>`

and like this:

`<marker> <path d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" stroke="red" strokeWidth="1px"> </marker>`

Both don't seem to work. How might I bypass this issue?

Here the complete code:

```html
<svg>
<g>
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="40" markerHeight="20" refX="0"
        refY="3.5" orient="auto" stroke="red" strokeWidth="10px">
            <path id ="arrow_marker" d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7"/>  
  
    <line  x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="#000" 
    strokeWidth="8" markerEnd="url(#arrowhead)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

```html
<svg>
<g>
    <defs>
        <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="40" markerHeight="20" refX="0"
        refY="3.5" orient="auto">
            <path id ="arrow_marker" d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
    <path stroke="red" strokeWidth="10px" d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7"/>  
  
    <line  x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="#000" 
    strokeWidth="8" markerEnd="url(#arrowhead)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I suspect you may have a css roule for the paths setting the stroke. Adding full working example to your question would be desirable.

Comment: because the CSS property is stroke-width and not strokeWidth.

Comment: did it originally with react, but replacing it with stroke-width doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marker width and height and the path units therein, are defined by default in units of stroke-width from the referring shape (aka your thick line). If you want to use "normal" units - then you have to specify markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse". You can't over-ride this by just adding "px" to your units. SVG is not like CSS and will not figure out that you mean pixels.

This version works fine.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px" viewBox="-100 -100 400 400">
<g>
    <defs>
        <marker markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="arrowhead" markerWidth="40" markerHeight="20" refX="0"
        refY="3.5" orient="auto" stroke-width="1">
            <path id ="arrow_marker" d="M0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" stroke="red" fill="red"/>
        </marker>
    </defs>

  
    <line  x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" stroke="#000" 
    stroke-width="8" marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" />
</g>
</svg>
```